# Array contains one or more value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is pulled from a database, basically I then want to have another array and if any values match between the two display them

Example:

```
$test1 = array(111, 465, 999, 000, 134, 555);
$test = array(111, 465);

if(in_array(array($test), $test1)){
   echo //some information
}
```

So if any value from `$test1` appears in `$test`, I want to output some info. But my code doesn't display anything. How can I do it?

**EDIT**
Further question derived from this [While statment with multiple values contained in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425840/while-statment-with-multiple-values-contained-in-an-array)

Comment: Use [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect) to achieve this:

```
if (count(array_intersect($test1, $test)) > 0) {
    # code...
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/145424)

Comment: Ok, that does what i asked originally. Now I would like to utilise somehting like this in an while statment, I didnt ask this beofre as i Thought once i get this bit i could work it out. Please see edit

Comment: @snookian That looks to be a lot different from the original question. Please post it as a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). (Make sure you describe the problem in detail. The better you describe, greater the chances of getting an **accurate** answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `count()` coupled with [`array_intersect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
if(count(array_intersect($test1,$test))>0)  //<---- Pointed out by Amal
{
    echo "Output something";
}
```

Comment: This will check if any of the values in `$test` are present in `$test1`. The OP wants to check if any of the values in `$test1` are present in `$test`, so this wouldn't work.