# While statment with multiple values contained in an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I have a database that holds several bits of info per entry. I use a while statement to loop through each one and display what I call "plots" which will be a number, each entry can hold multiple plots EG 111, 222, 333

what I need to do I have the while statement (or another method that may suit better) to check whether that plot numbers that each entry holds are contained within a array that I set and then display so information
EG:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($aa, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $plotsTotal1 = explode(" ", $row['exoutdoorspaceplottotals']);
    $plotsTotal2 = array_filter($plotsTotal1); 
    //this gets info from DB. an example of the data would be:
    //$plotsTotal2 = array(111, 555);

    $test = array(111, 465, 555, 666, 777);

    if (count(array_intersect($plotsTotal2, $test)) > 0) {
     echo 'something'; <br/>
    }
}
```

So $plotsTotal2 Is a combination if 3 arrays.

As an example If I have 3 entrys the the while statment will loop. 
entry one has plots, 111, 222, 465
entry two has plots, 666, 123, 412
entry three has plots, 000, 999

The while loop should display some information for (Probably the name and plots for each entry) so the outcome would be:

Entry one 111,222,465
Entry two 666, 123, 412

(entry three doesn't have matching numbers so therefore not displayed anything)

Any help appropriated, hope i explained this all ok.

Ian

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Could you reduce this code into a very minimal example? (Only that's required to demonstrate your problem. Take a look at http://sscce.org)

Comment: array_filter requires a function that returns true for each element you want to keep. Or are you just filtering out 0 values?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? [Tested here](http://3v4l.org/Oq0Cs) or [this while version](http://3v4l.org/dtviZ)

```
$entries = array(
    "111 222 465",
    "666 123 412",
    "000 999",
);

$test = array(111, 465, 555, 666, 777);

foreach ($entries as $key => $entry) {
    $plotsTotal1 = explode(' ', $entry);
    $plotsTotal2 = array_filter($plotsTotal1);

    $matches = array_intersect($test, $plotsTotal2);

    if (count($matches) > 0) {
        echo 'Entry ' . $key. ' contains ' . implode(',', $matches) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This just show one entry, there are for example two entrys that should match what is in the test array but it only displays the info for one.

Comment: Then it's not clear to me what you want. I've put something [online](http://3v4l.org/Oq0Cs)

Comment: This is where i get stuck. Your example works great, but I am not creating the $entries manually like that, I have to get it from a database. I been using a while loop to loop through each but I cant figure out how to work that into your example

Comment: What are the results from the database exactly? My example is very similar to the `while`-version. That cannot be the problem.

Comment: the results are stored in one field separated by a space. So for example the field is called exmainhallopenplottotals and would contain 111 222 333 (this amounts to 3 different plots). There are roughly at the moment 30 seperate entries which contain different numbers.

Comment: here are two exact entries: One 465 789789   Two: 555 111

Comment: @snookian I think your problem lays somewhere else. I've reworked the example using a while and sort of mocked the mysql result resource. Check [this](http://3v4l.org/dtviZ)